# ESM equivalent for createRequire(path).resolve(module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

I am working on a JavaScript instrumentation engine where I traverse a source file's AST and recursively enqueue imported modules for instrumentation as well. For that, I need to resolve a module name to its source file.

For CommonJS modules, this is really straightforward:

```js
/**
 * Resolves the given module to a path.
 * @param currentFilePath The file that is currently instrumented. Serves as base path for the resolver.
 * @param module The module to resolve to its file path.
 */
function resolveCommonJsModule(currentFilePath, module)
{
  let requireFunc = createRequire(currentFilePath);
  return requireFunc.resolve(module);
}
```

However, this does not work for ES modules loaded through `import`. If a library defines separate exports for ES and CommonJS modules in its *package.json*, this function will always return the CommonJS version. For example:

```json
...
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "import": "./esm/index.js",  <-- ES module
      "default": "./index.js"      <-- CommonJS module, which is returned by function above
    },
},
...
```

I know that there is [`import.meta.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta/resolve), but this does not allow me to set a "base path" from which resolution is done. Instead, it is relative to the instrumentation script, which resides in an entirely different directory.

**What is the ES module equivalent for resolving module names given a base path?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is an unstable overload [`import.meta.resolve(specifier, parent)`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#importmetaresolvespecifier), which would allow to resolve imports relative to a given `parent` module, similar to `require.resolve`.

However, it needs the `--experimental-import-meta-resolve` flag, and does not appear to work with all modules: Resolving `./file.mjs` is successful, but resolving `some-package` leads to an `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

Fortunately, I was able to find a ponyfill that works around the problem, [import-meta-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-meta-resolve):

```
import * as importMetaResolve from "import-meta-resolve";
import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url";

let modulePath = importMetaResolve.resolve(module, pathToFileURL(currentFilePath));
```

This command yields correct paths for all CommonJS and ES modules.